# msfeedssync.exe what does it do?

Tags: windows-7, tasks

I had a program `msfeedssync.exe` as a scheduled task on my machine.

Wondering what is this for and how did it get scheduled on my Windows 7 machine?

Comment: The task on my system periodically created a command window popup with taskeng.exe in the title bar.

Answer (score 58):

What is Msfeedssync.exe: 
It is the Microsoft Feeds Synchronization task found on PCs with Internet Explorer and which automatic RSS Feeds synchronization turned ON. This task starts up at the intervals specified in Internet Explorer and checks for updates to your RSS feeds. Once it has updated your RSS feeds, it terminates.

How to disable it: 
Control Panel > Internet Options > Content(tab) > Feeds and Web Slices > Settings(button)

From here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.internetexplorer.general/6wAVjHlHPns/8ZrnUriDgQ8J

Comment: +2 for showing us how to disable it.  If MS just put the appropriate explanations in their help files....but that would be rational wouldn't it??

Comment: Link to explain how to disable it no longer works (1/9/2019)

Comment: This scheduled tasks also exists on a Windows Server 2019, while the IE Feeds are disabled. Don't know why, yet.

Answer (score 10):

It is supposed to be the RSS feed updater for IE / whatever you're using RSS feeds for. There is also a little virus going around camoflaging msfeedssync.exe, so make sure that the scheduled task resides in a folder such as /system32. If you're not using any feeds, it's okay to disable this task.

Comment: I can concur that this file can be a camouflaged virus, be wary of it.